# JSON Server PUT request not found

Tags: json, rest

I've created a JSON server as a temporary backend service to read and edit user data.
When I do a read request like this:
http://localhost:3001/users?playerId=1193212
The read request is successful and I get the following response:

```html
[
    {
        "playerId": "1193212",
        "partnerId": "506",
        "email": "hhristova+qahriprmpaal16@gan.com",
        "alias": "qahriprmpaal16",
        "forename": "Christine",
        "surname": "Bell",
        "mobileNumber": "9792694595",
        "testAccount": "testAccount",
        "suspended": "accountSuspended"
    }
]
```

However, when I do a put request like this:

```html
PUT

http://localhost:3001/users?playerId=1193212
{
    "playerId" : "1193212",
    "suspended": "accountSuspended"
}
```

I get a 404 not found response.
How do I do a put request with JSON server?
I've also tried
http://localhost:3001/users/1193212
I'm sending accept and content-type headers = "application/json"

Comment: Did the read request of the first code snippet work? Consider editing your question to specify if it was or was not successful.

Comment: the original text shows the read request I sent and the response I got back (succesful, 202)

Comment: Good. Then I suggest putting "successful" before "read request like this". by editing your question. Sometimes the Comments are not read.

Comment: I figured it out. The 'playerId' attribute is not recognized as an id.  I tried using the command line configuration  --id playerId but even that doesn't change how the PUT works. So, I had to add an Id attribute to each element and copy over the playerId attribute.  Kind of a pain but it worked.